# Insert values at middle of list based on certain condition

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list called category which has below values.

```
`category=['Constant', 'Constant', 'Constant', 'Constant', 'Categorical', 'Categorical', 'Categorical', 'Categorical', 'Categorical', 'Constant', 'Constant', 'Categorical', 'Constant', 'Categorical', 'Categorical', 'Categorical', 'Categorical', 'Categorical', 'Constant', 'Categorical', 'Categorical', 'Categorical']`
```

I have to go through this list and create a new list and insert values called 'None' wherever the values are 'Constant'. But in my case I am able to insert 'None' only at the beginning(for first 4 values), unable to insert 'None' at middle of list. (For eg: I want to print 'None' at 10th and 11th, 13th position). Can you look at my code and tell me what mistake I am doing.

```
distinct = []
for x in category:
    if x == 'Constant':
        distinct.append('None')
    elif x == 'Categorical':
        distinctvalue = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("My XPath has list of items")
        for dv in distinctvalue:
            distval = dv.text
            distinct.append(distval)
        break
print(distinct)
```

O/P: I have got `['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', '1027', '1117', '2', '1117', '1027', '2', '2', '26', '2', '363', '96', '363', '339545', '96']`

Expected O/P: `['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', '1027', '1117', '2', '1117', '1027','None','None', '2', 'None', '2', '26', '2', '363', '96','None', '363', '339545', '96']`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the 'break' from your elif block of the code

```
elif x == 'Categorical':
    distinctvalue = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("My XPath has list of items")
    for dv in distinctvalue:
        distval = dv.text
        distinct.append(distval)
    break # remove this
```

Comment: I tried this, but it does not break my loop. It prints below:['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', '1027', '1117', '2', '1117', '1027', '2', '2', '26', '2', '363', '96', '363', '339545', '96', '1027', '1117', '2', '1117', '1027', '2', '2', '26', '2', '363', '96', '363', '339545', '96', '1027', '1117', '2', '1117', '1027', '2', '2', '26', '2', '363', '96', '363', '339545', '96', '1027', '1117', '2', '1117', '1027', '2', '2', '26', '2', '363', '96', '363', '339545', '96', '1027', '1117', '2', '1117', '1027', '2', '2', '26', '2', '363', '96', '363', .................]

Comment: The error is in the 2nd for loop, I guess. When it gets to the 2nd loop, it keeps iterating the list of values and keeps appending the values (dv.text) to the loop. You should rewrite the code to append only one value from the list. Can you share the xpath list?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to do the whole loop inside your `elif` - instead get the next value from the list when you need it.

There are two ways you could do this:

**By list indexing.**

Use an index variable (here `i`) to keep track of where you have reached in the list:

```
distinct = []
distinctvalue = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("My XPath has list of items")

i = 0  # <== initialise the index variable
for x in category:
    if x == 'Constant':
        distinct.append('None')
    elif x == 'Categorical':
        dv = distinctvalue[i]  # <== use the index variable to look up next value
        i += 1  # <== increment the counter ready for next time
        distval = dv.text
        distinct.append(distval)
print(distinct)
```

If you might run out of distinct values early, then you can put in a catch for this so that if it tries to get a next value and there isn't one then it will `break` from the loop instead -- replace:

```
        dv = distinctvalue[i]
```

with:

```
        try:
            dv = distinctvalue[i]
        except IndexError:
            break
```

**Using an iterator.**

This time we use `iter` to make an iterator from the list, and use `next` to get the next value from that iterator:

```
distinct = []
distinctvalue = iter(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("My XPath has list of items"))  # <== get the iterator

for x in category:
    if x == 'Constant':
        distinct.append('None')
    elif x == 'Categorical':
        dv = next(distinctvalue)  # <== next one
        distval = dv.text
        distinct.append(distval)
print(distinct)
```

This time, to exit the loop early if you runs out of values, you would replace:

```
        dv = next(distinctvalue)
```

with:

```
        try:
            dv = next(distinctvalue)
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it runs fine.

Comment: @Thiyagu Glad it's working for you - thanks for letting me know.